# GCC -O3 huge generated code - deselect an option?

Tags: gcc, optimization, compilation

When I compile certain loops with `-O3` I get enormous code, sometime with very complex-looking,long sequences of SIMD code. (Obviously I need to profile, but due to serious illness, I'm not able to use the necessary tools at the moment.) My question:

- I see that I should be able to keep `-O3`, but knock-out certain problematic options selectively? Using `-fno-foo`
- Which individual options should I scrutinise first? Potential culprits that are likely to be responsible for not only huge code bloat (so instruction or micro-ops cache size problems) but also true negative performance gain due to the sheer number of micro-ops generated?

Comment: I read an earlier closely related question, but didn't seem to find any real resolution. I've rather drowned in the docs. I'm also using the GDC (D language front end) compiler with backend for x86-64, I'm assuming that GDC takes all the same switches as the C compiler, pretty much, just with a few extra DLang-related ones added.

Comment: Another question reported that additive usage, building up a set of options starting from -O2 and adding extra individual switches doesn't sum to -O3 fully, for reasons unknown. The question of why not was unresolved.